# Bottom bar slides up with soft key board Android

Tags: android, android-layout

My XML code is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="430dp"
  android:fadingEdge="none"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"

  >    
 .......LinearLayout
    </ScrollView>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tabbarbottom"

    >

    <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  >

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/jobs"
     android:text="About Us"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="@drawable/white"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="12.5sp"
     ></Button>

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/aboutus"
     android:text="Value"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textColor="@drawable/white"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/jobs"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="12.5sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
     ></Button>

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/benefits"
     android:text="History"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="@drawable/white"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/aboutus"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_weight="1"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="12.5sp"
     ></Button>

     </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when ever user touches the edittext to type the bottom bar also rising up with keyboard.

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your manifest file.I think in this activity you set :android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" If after removing this line, problem is not fixed.Please contact with me.Yahoo+Skype:fsoft_duonghv.GoodLuck:)

Comment: No i have not set that ..am using android:name=".SearxhJobs" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" these properties only in in manifest

Comment: Sorry you only set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest.Please try again :)